# POSIX Shell: Replace special characters with their escaped version

Tags: string, shell, replace, escaping, posix

I have the misfortune of having to deal with Windows machines occasionally. Windows likes doing weird things like using backslashes for separators, even for their username. For example, the output of the command `whoami /user` might output something like `azuread\testman`.

This is a problem for me when I need to use these things further on in my scripts. Astute observers may notice that `azuread\testman` will be interpreted as `azuread   estman` in many contexts.

So, the problem I'm encountering is that these strings end up stored in my variables and wreak havoc further down the line. In particular, the issue is with characters following a backslash like `\n` and `\t`, but there might be some other edge cases I'm not aware of too.

Most of the solutions to similar problems I've found seem to assume either that I can directly manipulate the string because I typed it in manually in the script (not the case), or that I'm using e.g. Bash for access to `printf "%q"` or `${var@Q}`, but this is not something I want to use here, POSIX Shell only.

Best solution I have so far is something like:

```bash
var=$(echo "${var}" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' -e 's/\t/\\t/g' -e 's/\n/\\n/g')
```

Which *seems* to work okay, at least for my immediate issue, but this definitely feels like the type of thing that's got a million edge cases, and *will* blow up in my face. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this that can perhaps catch more edge cases with special characters or otherwise function better?

Comment: Usually the solution is not to add escapes to your data, but to avoid using it in a context where escapes are processed. For example, given `var=azuread\testman`,  compare `printf "$var"` and `printf '%s\n' "$var"`.

Comment: In my particular case, I have a Python script embedded in a here doc using the variable. For that particular usecase, I don't think there's any way around escaping the data. Even trying to use e.g. raw strings still won't work because the substitution seems to occur during the actual here doc instantiation, rather than being typed as "normal".

Comment: you still don't need to escape anything. if you export the variable (`export var`) python can use it directly (`os.environ['var']`)

Comment: Oh hey, that's very cool. Seems like a much better solution, thanks!